# Does 'Clone' (spell) Work On A Flesh Golem?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Does [Clone](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Clone#content) work on a [Flesh golem](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Flesh%20Golem#content)?

Points of possible interest:

- golem is the right size
- clone doesn't seem to 'change their shape'
- does the golem 'die'? does it live?

Seems like a pretty straightforward question, am I missing something?

Comment: I edited out the bit about unwritten stack exchange rules since the sentence didn’t contribute anything to the question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Thank you / excellent work. I normally do a much, much longer explanation but i honestly couldn't think of a thing. And it worked! The answer below is excellent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No, as  Golems are not alive.

From the spell *Clone*:

> This spell grows an inert duplicate of a living creature as a safeguard against death...

So the spell requires a living target.  From the description of Golems, we see  they are not living ([*MM p.167*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/monster-manual#Golems)):

> After constructing the body …, the golems  creator infuses it with a spirit from the  Elemental Plane of Earth.

The golem is merely infused with some form of an Earth Elemental; it has no soul, and thus its soul cannot be moved to a new body through the *Clone* spell.